# Python pandas - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column named `year` in object format. I want to convert object to int but I have this error :

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2021.0'

Here is my code :
`data_h_df['year'].astype(str).astype(int)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert to floats, then to integers:

```
data_h_df['year'].astype(float).astype(int)
```

If there are `NaN`s use `Int64` for integers with `NaN`s:

```
data_h_df['year'].astype(float).astype('Int64')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df['year'] = df['year'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0.0)
```

The code does two things：

1. Convert all column types to numeric types, fill in NaN for errors,
   and fill in 0 for NaNs
2. After this operation, the column of object (the string type stored
   in the column) is converted to float

Answer (score 1):

Assign 'ignore' to the 'errors' perameter.

```
>>> data_h_df['year'].astype(float).astype(int, errors='ignore')
>>> data_h_df['year']
0    2021.0
1    2022.0
2       NaN
3       2.0
dtype: float64
```